# pisa html2pdf convert table dont apply height to td

Tags: html-table, html2pdf, pisa

I use **pisa xhtml2pdf** to convert an html code to pdf.

I have a problem! pisa did not apply some style to my table such as **height** and **vertical-align**

```
<table style='overflow: hidden;' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' 
width="300px">
<tr style="background-color : yellow; height:100px;">
<td style="color: red; height:100px; vertical-align: middle;">
A lot of  data
</td></tr></table>
```

but after converting this html to pdf, height of table tds and vertical-align did not correct!
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a height (`height:100px;`) to the table too example for you :

```
<table style='overflow: hidden; height:100px;' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width="300px">
    <tr style="background-color : yellow;height:100px;">
        <td style="color: red; height:100px; vertical-align: middle;">
            <!-- A lot of  data -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can't apply any height to "div, table, tr, td" element

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the height of the cell with this hack:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td width="100%" style="border: 1px solid #000"><!-- content goes here --></td>
    <td width="0"><br><br><br><br><br></td><!-- special cell to keep the height of the table -->
</tr>
</table>
```

The second cell is completely invisible and the code above draws a box of 100% in width and the height is defined by amount of <br>s in the second cell or amount of the text in the first cell (whichever comes longer)